# How to prepare time table in the desired format?

Tags: tables

I am expected to prepare a time table in the format shown below:[image: 1]
However, I am only able to generate this:[image: 2]

Following is the code which I've with me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,landscape]{book}
\usepackage[inner=0.3in,outer=0.3in,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

%\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
%\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|
>{\columncolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}}c |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{19}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}{\Huge Student Meeting Times and Schedule : Jan--July 2016}}\\ 
\hline
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}08:30\\ 09:00\end{tabular} 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}09:00\\ 09:30\end{tabular} 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}09:30\\ 10:00\end{tabular} 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}10:00\\ 10:30\end{tabular}                 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}10:30\\ 11:00\end{tabular} 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}11:00\\ 11:30\end{tabular}                 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}11:30\\ 12:00\end{tabular}         
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}12:00\\ 12:30\end{tabular}                 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}12:30\\ 13:00\end{tabular}             
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}13:00\\ 14:00\end{tabular}                 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}14:00\\ 14:30\end{tabular}  
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}14:30\\ 15:00\end{tabular}  
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}15:00\\ 15:30\end{tabular}                 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}15:30\\ 16:00\end{tabular} 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}16:00\\ 16:30\end{tabular} 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}16:30\\ 17:00\end{tabular} 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}17:00\\ 17:30\end{tabular} 
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}17:30\\ 18:30\end{tabular} 
\\ 
\hline
Mon 
& & 
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009901}\textbf{Aa Rr}}           
& \cellcolor[HTML]{F8A102}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sssss\\ Hhhh\end{tabular}} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}GGGGGGGGG \\ MMMMMM\end{tabular}}}                                             
& \cellcolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}                                              
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{34CDF9}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sssss \&\\ Mmmm\end{tabular}}} 
& \cellcolor[HTML]{F8A102}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sssss\\ Hhhh\end{tabular}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009901}\textbf{Pp Nn}}           
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009901}\textbf{Aa Mm}}         
&                                                       
\\ 

\cline{1-10} \cline{12-19} 

Tue 
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFC9E}\textbf{E 2 : Class}}  
& \cellcolor[HTML]{F8A102}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sssss\\ Hhhh\end{tabular}} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009901}\textbf{Cc Mm}}       
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{34CDF9}\textbf{Aa Dd}}           
& \cellcolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}                                              
& &
& \cellcolor[HTML]{F8A102}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sssss\\ Hhhh\end{tabular}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009901}\textbf{Aa Mm}}          
& & & 
\\ 

\cline{1-10} \cline{12-19} 

Wed
& & 
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009901}\textbf{Pp Gg}}          
& \cellcolor[HTML]{F8A102}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sssss\\ Hhhh\end{tabular}} 
& \cellcolor[HTML]{340096}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Tt Kk}} 
&                                                                       
& \cellcolor[HTML]{340096}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Hh Ss}} 
& \cellcolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}                                              
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{3531FF}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Cc}}}
& \cellcolor[HTML]{F8A102}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sssss\\ Hhhh\end{tabular}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{3531FF}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Cc}}}
& & & 
\\ 

\cline{1-10} \cline{12-19} 

Thu 
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFC9E}\textbf{E 2 : Class}}  
& \cellcolor[HTML]{F8A102}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sssss\\ Hhhh\end{tabular}} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009901}\textbf{Ss Rr}}         
& \cellcolor[HTML]{F8A102}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sssss\\ Hhhh\end{tabular}} 
&
& \cellcolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}                                              
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{34CDF9}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Vv \&\\ Ss\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{3531FF}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Cc}}}
& & & & 
\\ 

\cline{1-10} \cline{12-19} 

Fri
& & & 
& \cellcolor[HTML]{34CDF9}\textbf{Aa Jj}                                 
& \cellcolor[HTML]{34CDF9}\textbf{Ss Jj}                
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Ff\\ Mm\end{tabular}}}                               & &
& \multirow{-8}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}L\\ U\\ N\\ C\\ H\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}GGGGGGGGG \\ MMMMMM\end{tabular}}}                                                 
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}\textbf{Ll Ss}}     
& & 
\\ 

\hline

\cellcolor[HTML]{C2E7C2}Sat 
& \multicolumn{18}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C2E7C2}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}~\\ ~\end{tabular}}} 
\\ 

\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: You can use \arrayrulewidth=1pt (for example), and \rowcolor also affects \hline.  Alternatively, you could redo the entire table using a tikz matrix.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I tried with \arrayrulewidth=1pt by uncommenting the line in the code given above. It didn't give desired results.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution (hopefully). I introduced some shortcut-macros to shorten typing repetitive code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,landscape]{book}
\usepackage[inner=0.3in,outer=0.3in,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,  x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell, hhline} 
\usepackage{tabstackengine} 
\setstackEOL{\\}
\renewcommand\theadset{\cellcolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries\cellcolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}\color{IndianRed3}}
\renewcommand\cellset{\mdseries}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{1ex}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{1ex}
\def\thickvrule{\vrule width 1.5mm}
\def\bluevrule{\color[HTML]{BBDAFF}\vrule width1pt}

 \begin{document}
\setlength\Lstackgap{1cm}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\begin{table}[]
\centering\sffamily\bfseries
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5mm}
\newcommand\SsHh{\multicolumn{1}{Sc}{ \cellcolor[HTML]{F8A102}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sssss\\ Hhhh\end{tabular}}}
\newcommand\Cc{\multicolumn{2}{Sc}{\cellcolor[HTML]{3531FF}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}Cc}}}
\newcommand\Greencells[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{Sc}{\cellcolor[HTML]{009901}#2}}
\newcommand\Lightbluecells[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{Sc}{\cellcolor[HTML]{34CDF9}#2}}
\newcommand\emptycells[1]{\multicolumn{#1}{Sc}{}}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{!{\thickvrule}Sc!{\thickvrule} *{8}{Sc!{\bluevrule}}
Sc!{\bluevrule}>{\columncolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}}Sc!{\bluevrule}*{7}{Sc!{\bluevrule}}Sc!{\thickvrule}}
\hhline{*{19}{-}}
\multicolumn{19}{!{\thickvrule}Sc!{\thickvrule}}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}{\Huge Student Meeting Times and Schedule : Jan--July 2016}}\\
\hhline{*{19}{-}}
& \makecell{08:30\\ 09:00}
& \makecell{09:00\\ 09:30}
& \makecell{09:30\\ 10:00}
& \makecell{10:00\\ 10:30}
& \makecell{10:30\\ 11:00}
& \makecell{11:00\\ 11:30}
& \makecell{11:30\\ 12:00}
& \makecell{12:00\\ 12:30}
& \makecell{12:30\\ 13:00}
& \makecell{13:00\\ 14:00}
& \makecell{14:00\\ 14:30}
& \makecell{14:30\\ 15:00}
& \makecell{15:00\\ 15:30}
& \makecell{15:30\\ 16:00}
& \makecell{16:00\\ 16:30}
& \makecell{16:30\\ 17:00}
& \makecell{17:00\\ 17:30}
& \makecell{17:30\\ 18:30}
\\
\hhline{*{19}{-}}

Mon
&\emptycells{2} & \Greencells{3}{Aa Rr}%
& \SsHh
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color{white}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}GGGGGGGGG \\ MMMMMM\end{tabular}}}
& \cellcolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{34CDF9}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sssss \&\\ Mmmm\end{tabular}}
& \SsHh%
& \Greencells{2}{Pp Nn}
& \Greencells{2}{Aa Mm} 
&
\\
\hhline{*{10}{-}>{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}*{8}{-}}

Tue
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFC9E}\color{IndianRed3}E 2 : Class} 
& \SsHh
& \Greencells{3}{Cc Mm} 
& \Lightbluecells{2}{Aa Dd}
& \cellcolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}
& \emptycells{2}
& \SsHh
& \Greencells{2}{Aa Mm}
&  \emptycells{2}  & 
\\
\hhline{*{10}{-}>{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}*{8}{-}}

Wed
&  \emptycells{2}
& \Greencells{3}{Pp Gg}
& \SsHh
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{340096}{\color{white}Tt Kk}}
&  \emptycells{1} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{340096}{\color{white}Hh Ss}}
& \cellcolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}
& \Cc
&\SsHh
& \Cc
&  \emptycells{2} &
\\
\hhline{*{10}{-}>{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}*{8}{-}}

Thu
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFC9E}\color{IndianRed3}E 2 : Class}
& \SsHh
& \Greencells{3}{Ss Rr}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8A102}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sssss\\ Hhhh\end{tabular}}
& \emptycells{1}
& \cellcolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{34CDF9}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Vv \&\\ Ss\end{tabular}}
& \Cc
&  \emptycells{3} &
\\
\hhline{*{10}{-}>{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{BBDAFF}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}*{8}{-}}

Fri
&  \emptycells{3}
& \Lightbluecells{1}{Aa   Jj}
& \Lightbluecells{1}{Ss Jj}
& \multicolumn{2}{Sc}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Ff\\ Mm\end{tabular}} & 
 \emptycells{2} 
& \multirowthead{-12}{L\\ U\\ N\\ C\\ H}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}GGGGGGGGG \\ MMMMMM\end{tabular}}}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}Ll Ss}
&  \emptycells{1}  &
\\
\hhline{*{19}{-}}
\rowcolor[HTML]{C2E7C2}
Sat
& \multicolumn{18}{c|}{\Gape[21pt][16pt]{}}
\\
\hhline{*{19}{-}}

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]